# file to import not found or unreadable: util/util in my switch from foundation 5 to foundation 6

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, compass-sass, compass, zurb-foundation-6

I used to use foundation 5 which uses compass to do the sass thing. but now i switch to foundation 6, I always cannot make it right. when running gulp,it show error:

```
file to import not found or unreadable: util/util
```

there is one answer i found here:http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/36389-what-is-import-utilutil, which says foundation 6 use libsass, but i donot know libsass and do want to use compass since i have used commpass mixins and function the like in my project already.  and i tried the ways they said but not succeed.
anyone know how to use foundation 6 using compass? btw, i use command line to generate the foundation project with all the tools i need and then I copy and paste my old project using foundation 5 and grunt into the new foundation 6 Folder. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Look in your settings file and double check the util import at the top is correct.